# When do the holes in semiconductor appear?

Tags: semiconductors, physics, electron

I'm trying to understand the concept of semiconductors, as far as I know whenever an electron moves it leaves a hole, so how can we say (for example) that n-type semiconductor has a majority of \$e^-\$, won't every electron let a hole?

Comment: No, because that's not how a hole is defined. A hole is a vacancy in the valence orbital resulting from having fewer electrons than a full orbital.

Comment: See the picture of the lattice structure at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/dope.html

Comment: An n-type semiconductor has extra electrons only because it is doped with materials which by nature have more than 4 electrons to make bonds with in their normal states.  Since silicon can only make four bonds, and these dopant atoms are forced into a silicon structure, their 5th electron has nothing to make a stable bond with, and so it floats about the lattice - free to drift under the influence of electric fields and contribute to conduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are confusing is the **application/use** of semiconductors with the **manufacture** of the semiconductors.
The of type semiconductor is determined by the type of "impurities" added by the **manufacturer** to the silicon.  If the impurity has more electrons than it needs, it is an n-type, if it has fewer electrons than it needs, it is a p-type.  These materials, when vapor deposited "next to each other", form a **p-n junction (band).**
Now, when you **apply** a forward bias the junction, the electrons of the n-type material will be pushed into the "holes" of the p-type material leaving holes on the n-type side of the junction (which will be filled with new electrons coming from the negative side of the supply).  The electrons that went into the p-type are attracted to the positive side of the supply leaving holes on the p-type side of the junction.
So it is clear that a "hole" is created when an electron moves, but the electron would not be able to move, in the first place, if there were no "holes," to move into!